# Angular JS ng-repeat to display data from JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to display data on the front end using the ng-repeat in Angular JS . This is my JSON output

```
    {
"success": false,
"timestamp": 1481126855178,
"errors": [{
    "message": "Please Enter Valid Format in Beginning Time"
}, {
    "message": "Please Enter Valid Format in Ending Time"
}, {
    "message": " Please Enter only one value in d/L/P box only "
}],
"StatusList": []
}
```

I am trying to display the messages, inside the errors.This is my HTML Code

```
 <table>
<tr ng-repeat='item in errorsd'>
<td align="left" class="validationMsg">&nbsp;{{item.message}}</td></tr>
```

The Problem here is it is getting displayed like this on HTML

```
     {"message":"Please Enter Valid Format in Beginning Time"}
     {"message":"Please Enter Valid Format in Ending Time"}
     {"message":" Please Enter only one value in D/L/P box only "}
```

I want to skip those message : part in the HTML and display the Remaining Output.I am trying to make my output like this .

```
 "Please Enter Valid Format in Beginning Time"
 "Please Enter Valid Format in Ending Time"
 " Please Enter only one value in D/L/P box only "
```

Comment: please add a jsfiddle/codepen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly access the **`message`**

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    "success": false,
    "timestamp": 1481126855178,
    "errors": [{
      "message": "Please Enter Valid Format in Beginning Time"
    }, {
      "message": "Please Enter Valid Format in Ending Time"
    }, {
      "message": " Please Enter only one value in d/L/P box only "
    }],
    "StatusList": []
  }


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Custom Plunker</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <table>
    

    <tr ng-repeat="(metric, metricData) in data.errors">
      <td>{{metricData.message}}</td>
    </tr>


  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeeth ! you are a genius. It worked like a Charm

Comment: I did it , it asked me to wait for some time

Comment: hey @sajeetharan, can you answer this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028797/ngrepeatdupes-error-when-trying-to-display-message-on-html

Answer (score 0):

`item.message.message` would probably give you what you want, but you should figure out why the first message object is not producing the desired text in the first place.

It looks like your error array is of type:

```
Error[obj {message: 'msg'}, ...]
```

So your ng-repeat is printing the object instead of the desired property.

Comment: can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028797/ngrepeatdupes-error-when-trying-to-display-message-on-html continuation of this question