# ngRepeat:dupes error When trying to display message on html

Tags: javascript, html, json, validation

I'm getting response from REST API and i'm trying to populate those error messages on the screen using HTML ,This case works fine.But whenever there is a success Case my Json gets varied and when i try to populate that on the HTML i'm getting an error such as [ngRepeat:dupes] . I tried adding trackby $index . [ngRepeat:dupes] disappears but still it doesnt get printed on HTML.This is my HTML

```
   <div ng-show="errorui">
       <table>          
        <tr ng-repeat='(item, itemData) in dbresponse.errors'>
        <td align="left" class="validationMsg"><img src="images/red_bullet.gif" border="0" width="8" height="8" alt="">&nbsp;{{itemData.message}}</td></tr>
    </table> 
  </div>

<div ng-show="successui">
    <table>         
        <tr ng-repeat='list in successresponse'>
        <td align="left" class="validationMsg"><img src="images/red_bullet.gif" border="0" width="8" height="8" alt="">&nbsp;{{list}}</td></tr>
    </table> 
</div>
```

This is my JSON output for Error CASE (errorui div in HTML). This works fine

```
{
"success": false,
"timestamp": 1481126855178,
"errors": [{
    "message": "Please Enter Valid Format in Beginning Time"
}, {
    "message": "Please Enter Valid Format in Ending Time"
}, {
    "message": " Please Enter only one value in d/L/P box only "
}],
"StatusList":[]  }
```

This is my JSON output for success case ,Now when i try to display it on screen i'm getting the error

```
    {
"success": true,
"timestamp": 1481150829322,
"message": "Configuration has been Added Successfully",
"eurexStatusList": []
}
```

This is my Controller Part

```
  $http.post('http://localhost:8080/services/add-config', dataobj)
       .then(function(response) {
      $scope.dbresponse = response.data;
      console.log($scope.dbresponse);
      if($scope.dbresponse.success != true){
           $scope.errorui = true;
      }else {
                  $scope.successresponse = $scope.dbresponse.message;
                  console.log($scope.successresponse);
                  $scope.successui = true;
              }
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan can you answer this

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer , the message is an String Value not an list of object . I tried to output the message like this and it worked {{successresponse}} .Thanks Everyone